# Perl Net::MAC::Vendor OUI

Tags: macos, perl

The follow is on MacOS High Sierra with Perl v5.28.2. The version of Net::MAC::Vendor is 1.265. This sort of a repeat post. My prior post lacked a lot of detail.

I am trying to put together a script to list ip addresses, MAC addresses, and vendors on a network. The  Net::MAC::Vendor::lookup function is returning a timeout error amongst other things. I have checked a few IEEE links that were supposed to have the OUI data but they are all dead returning no data. I have seen a number of mentions stating the file can be found in some installations of linux. I have search high and low and have not found an oui.txt file on my system. If I downloaded a copy I wouldn't know where to put it or how I could have the Net::MAC::Vendor function to locate it. Also, if I did find a link I still wouldn't know how to direct the vendor lookup function to use it.

The errors I am getting are as follows:

Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/{username}/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.2/lib/site_perl/5.28.2/Net/MAC/Vendor.pm line 320.
Failed fetching [https://services13.ieee.org/RST/standards-ra-web/rest/assignments/download/?registry=MA-L&format=html&text=D8-D7-75] HTTP status []
message [Connect timeout] at simplemacvendor.pl line 23.
Could not fetch data from the IEEE! at simplemacvendor.pl line 23.

```
The sample code:

    #!/usr/bin/perl;
    use strict;
    use feature qw(say);
    use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
    use Net::MAC::Vendor;

    open(ARP, "arp -na|") || die "Failed $!\n";
    my @arp_table;
    while (<ARP>) {
        if ($_ =~ m/incomplet/) {next;}
        if ($_ =~ m/Address/) {next;}
        my @line = split(' ',$_);
        my $computer = {};

        $line[1] =~ s/(\()([0-9\.]*)(\))/\2/;
        $computer->{ip} = $line[1];
        $computer->{mac}  = $line[3];
        $computer->{if}  = $line[5];

        say Dumper($computer);

    # Get vendor info
        my $vendor_info = Net::MAC::Vendor::lookup( $computer->{mac} ); # line 23
        $computer->{vendor} = $vendor_info->[0];
        push @arp_table , $computer;
    }

    print "ARP Table with vendors:\n";
    for my $i (0 .. $#arp_table) {
        print "$arp_table[$i]{ip}\t";
        print "$arp_table[$i]{if}\t";
        print "$arp_table[$i]{mac}\t";
        print "$arp_table[$i]{vendor}";
        print "\n";
    }
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MAC::Vendor), you can set the environment variable `NET_MAC_VENDOR_OUI_URL` to try a new url for the OUI file. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have not found a site yet. I came across one site that listed a number of urls but allow were down. Would the variable work for local files?